# Doctrine Array Hydration with db column names keys

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using the latest Doctrine (2.4)
Given this simple entity:

```
class Booking
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="from_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $fromDate;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="deposit_price", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $depositPrice;
}
```

If I do a simple ORM query with array Hydration the result I get back is something like this:

```
[
   'id'=>1,
   'depositPrice'=>100.5,
   'fromDate'=>'2012-01-01'
]
```

Is there a simple way to Hydrate using the actual column fields? To get a result like this:

```
[
    'id'=>1,
    'deposit_price'=>100.5,
    'from_date'=>'2012-01-01'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 solutions:

- You can create [custom hydration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes) and do in it what you want.
- You can use [Native query and Result Set Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).
- You can just rename your fields in your Entity class.

I would prefer 3rd case. It is so easy to rename your fields. You can do it on all files with regular expressions (if it is supported by your IDE).

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried all but the 3rd option already and it seemed like to much work if I want to do it many times across the whole project. So I will try no.3 today... I was unsure wether it would work...

Comment: Try to find and replace by regular expressions

Comment: The option no.3 is the one I'm going to use from now on... Seems that the simplest solutions sometimes are the best ones..Thanks ;)